Send log to GrayLog simply (with curl?)
Is there a simple way to send logs to my GrayLog server? Without having to install any package on the client VMs. No fluent-bit, no beat.
Perhaps a curl based solution
(a script that runs in background, including a curl combined with a tail -f)?

there are curl examples in the graylog docu, but your options depend on what inputs you have configured in graylog
